# NullPointerException in MyFaces facelet inclusion

Tags: facelets, jsf-2.2, myfaces

I'm trying to migrate simple JSF2.2 prototype from **Mojarra** 2.2.5 (... where works fine ...) to **MyFaces** 2.2.3 but a **NullPointerException** occurs.
What I normally do using Mojarra is to include (inject) **programmatically** a JSF page within a container.

The sample inclusion page (*inclusion.xhtml*) is:

```xhtml
<h:panelGroup id="container">
</h:panelGroup>
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="Include page" action="#{inclusion.include('included.xhtml')}" />
</h:form>
```

The **included** page (*included.xhtml*) contains something like:

```xhtml
    <h:outputText value="INCLUDED TEXT ..." />
```

This is the **managed bean**:

```java
    @ManagedBean(name="inclusion")
    @RequestScoped
    public final class Inclusion {

    public void include(String contentUrl) throws IOException{
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();        
        FaceletContext f2ctx = (FaceletContext) fc.getAttributes().get(FaceletContext.FACELET_CONTEXT_KEY);
        UIComponent uic = fc.getViewRoot().findComponent("container");
        if (uic != null && f2ctx != null) {
            f2ctx.includeFacelet(uic, contentUrl);              
        }
    }
```

This is the **Exception**:

> javax.el.ELException: java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> viewId=/inclusion.xhtml
>   location=/opt/jbdevstudio7/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/jsf2test/inclusion.xhtml
>   phaseId=INVOKE_APPLICATION(5)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException -
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.FaceletCompositionContextImpl.generateUniqueId(FaceletCompositionContextImpl.java:1045)
>
> /inclusion.xhtml at line 15 and column 91
>   action="#{inclusion.include('included.xhtml')}"  - State size:0 bytes

This is the **stacktrace**:

> org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareELException:
>   javax.el.ELException: java.lang.NullPointerException  at
>   org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.invoke(ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:74)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener.processAction(DialogActionListener.java:45)
>     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:120)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastAll(UIViewRoot.java:1172)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:365)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1656)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:862)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:42)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:196)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:143)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:198)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at jplus.web.filters.FlowFilter.doFilter(FlowFilter.java:215)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) Caused by:
>   javax.el.ELException: java.lang.NullPointerException  at
>   org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:291)   at
>   org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.invoke(ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.java:96)
>     ... 33 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.FaceletCompositionContextImpl.generateUniqueId(FaceletCompositionContextImpl.java:1045)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.generateUniqueId(DefaultFaceletContext.java:322)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.UIInstructionHandler.apply(UIInstructionHandler.java:87)
>     at
>   javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:514)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:568)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:546)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:240)
>     at Inclusion.include(Inclusion.java:27)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)   ... 35 more

What do you think about ?
Is there a bug ?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a bug. Use FaceletContext is the wrong way to do it, because later it causes duplicate id and state management issues, that does not have solution because from start the code is wrong. Instead, try use this way:

```
        ViewDeclarationLanguage vdl = facesContext.getApplication().
            getViewHandler().getViewDeclarationLanguage(
                facesContext, facesContext.getViewRoot().getViewId());

        Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        attributes.put("src", "/addSimpleIncludeVDL_1_1.xhtml");
        UIComponent component = vdl.createComponent(facesContext, 
            "http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets", 
            "include", attributes);
        getChildren().add(component);
```

vdl.createComponent(...) was added in JSF 2.2, and in MyFaces it was improved to allow this usage. You can even add composite components programmatically in this way. In MyFaces users list it has been reported that this way works very well.

Comment: Your suggestion works GREAT !!!
This approach is what I was looking for a long time ...
Sincere Thanks.