# How to use FaceletContext.includeFacelet() properly?

Tags: jsf, facelets, managed-bean, programmatically-created, uiinclude

I am using Mojarra 2.2.8 and Primefaces 5.2. I need to include different facelets on ajax request, so i use this code in managed bean:

```
FaceletContext faceletContext = (FaceletContext) context.getAttributes().get(FaceletContext.FACELET_CONTEXT_KEY);
if (type.equals("default")) {
        faceletContext.includeFacelet(this, "/defaultDlg.xhtml");
}
```

In *defaultDlg.xhtml* i have Primefaces dynamic tabView:

```
<p:tabView id="contentTabView" onTabShow="PF('contentDlg').initPosition();" dynamic="true">
    <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{folderView.onTabChange}"/>
    <p:tab title="#{msg['title.documentCard']}">
        <p:panel>

            <!--  some widgets here... -->

        </p:panel>
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="#{msg['title.performance']}">
        <!--  DataTable with subTable ... -->
        <p:dataTable  value="#{folderView.performance}" 
                                id="historyTable" widgetVar="historyTable" var="wf">
            <p:columnGroup type="header">
                <p:row>
                    <p:column headerText="#{msg['audit.performance.sendbydesc']}" />
                    <p:column  headerText="#{msg['audit.performance.performerdesc']}" />
                </p:row>
            </p:columnGroup>

            <p:subTable var="task" value="#{wf[5]}">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="#{wf[2]}" />
                </f:facet>
                <p:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{task[2]}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{task[4]}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:subTable>
        </p:dataTable>
    </p:tab>
    <!--  more tabs ... -->
```

I looked [this answer on related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24578871/6065134) where user says that *"Use FaceletContext is the wrong way to do it, because later it causes duplicate id and state management issues"* without any explanation. In my example this method correctly includes UIComponents from *defaultDlg.xhtml* to view root and renders them on page.

But when i click on second tab with subTable or make any ajax request i get this error:

> Severe: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Trying to extract rowIndex from clientId 'ntikDoc:contentTabView:historyTable:j_id492561291_69346d22:j_id492561291_69346d58' For input string: "j_id492561291_69346d22"
>       at javax.faces.component.UIData.invokeOnComponent(UIData.java:1021)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:1503)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:713)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:1503)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:713)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:1503)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:713)
>       at org.primefaces.component.api.UITabPanel.invokeOnComponent(UITabPanel.java:798)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:1503)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:713)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:1503)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:713)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:1503)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:713)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:1503)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:713)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:1503)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:713)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:1503)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:713)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:1503)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:713)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.locateComponentByClientId(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:2063)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.reapplyDynamicAdd(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:2127)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.reapplyDynamicActions(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:2114)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:961)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
>       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor167.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:323)
>       at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:321)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:536)
>       at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:356)
>       at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:212)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1543)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:88)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:200)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:197)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:196)
>       at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:88)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:200)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:197)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:196)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I thik that there might be a problem with state saving during ajax request because if i remove subTable from second tab i get this warnings on every ajax request:

> Warning: Unable to save dynamic action with clientId 'ntikDoc:j_id69584408_969820d' because the UIComponent cannot be found
>   Warning: Unable to save dynamic action with clientId 'ntikDoc:j_id69584408_969820d_1' because the UIComponent cannot be found
>   Warning: Unable to save dynamic action with clientId 'ntikDoc:idtFrom:j_id69584408_969829e' because the UIComponent cannot be found
>   Warning: Unable to save dynamic action with clientId 'ntikDoc:idtFrom:j_id69584408_96982b4' because the UIComponent cannot be found
>   Warning: Unable to save dynamic action with clientId 'ntikDoc:j_id69584408_96983ee' because the UIComponent cannot be found
>   Warning: Unable to save dynamic action with clientId 'ntikDoc:idtTo:j_id69584408_9698056' because the UIComponent cannot be found
>   Warning: Unable to save dynamic action with clientId 'ntikDoc:idtTo:j_id69584408_969806c' because the UIComponent cannot be found
>   Warning: Unable to save dynamic action with clientId 'ntikDoc:idtTo:j_id69584408_969800a' because the UIComponent cannot be found
>   Warning: Unable to save dynamic action with clientId 'ntikDoc:contentTabView:j_id492561291_69346015' because the UIComponent cannot be found
>   Warning: Unable to save dynamic action with clientId 'ntikDoc:contentTabView:j_id492561291_69346015_1' because the UIComponent cannot be found
>   Warning: Unable to save dynamic action with clientId 'ntikDoc:contentTabView:contentTable:j_id492561291_69346b92' because the UIComponent cannot be found
>   Warning: Unable to save dynamic action with clientId 'ntikDoc:contentTabView:contentTable:j_id492561291_69346bfc' because the UIComponent cannot be found
>   Warning: Unable to save dynamic action with clientId 'ntikDoc:contentTabView:perTable:j_id492561291_69346cc4' because the UIComponent cannot be found
>   Warning: Unable to save dynamic action with clientId 'ntikDoc:contentTabView:perTable:j_id492561291_69346c26' because the UIComponent cannot be found
>   Warning: Unable to save dynamic action with clientId 'ntikDoc:contentTabView:perTable:j_id492561291_69346c10' because the UIComponent cannot be found
>   Warning: Unable to save dynamic action with clientId 'ntikDoc:contentTabView:historyTable:j_id492561291_69346d22:j_id492561291_69346d6e' because the UIComponent cannot be found
>   Warning: Unable to save dynamic action with clientId 'ntikDoc:contentTabView:historyDocTable:j_id492561291_69346ef9' because the UIComponent cannot be found

So how to use `faceletContext.includeFacelet` correctly?

Comment: Instructions how to use it properly (in a backing bean) is already given in the answer which you found. Have you tried it? The `includeFacelet` works only correctly during view build time, but apparently you executed it after the view is being built (e.g. in bean action method).

Comment: I cant create ui:include component with ViewDeclarationLanguage in mojarra implementation because ui:include does not have a backing component (see this https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3281 ) . So solution from that answer works only for MyFaces

Comment: I see. Have you considered `<ui:include src="#{bean.src}">` instead? Perhaps wrapped with a `<c:if test="#{not empty bean.src}">` if it could be empty.

Comment: Yes. I came to using `<ui:include src="#{bean.src}">` wrapped with `<p:outputPanel rendered="#{bean.src ne null}"/>` and it works. Now i'm just curious why `includeFacelet` doesn't work.

Comment: lu4242 already answered it. It corrupts JSF state.